# Moq to verify certain value not predicable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

To make it easy to explain, I have following codes

```
public interface IAnother
{
    void DoAnotherJob(DateTime date);
}

public class MainJob
{
    private IAnother another;

    public MainJob(IAnother another)
    {
        this.another = another;
    }

    public void FunctionA()
    {
        this.FunctionB(DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void FunctionB(DateTime date)
    {
        this.another.DoAnotherJob(date);
    }
}
```

I need to write a unit test code to make sure when `FunctionA()` is called the underlying `IAnother.DoAnotherJob()` is called to use the current date time.

I can write the testing code

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void FunctionATest()
    {
        var mockAnother = new Mock<IAnother>();

        var mainJob = new MainJob(mockAnother.Object);

        mainJob.FunctionA();

        mockAnother.Verify(x => x.DoAnotherJob(It.IsAny<DateTime>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

to make sure the function is called with any date time, but I have no way to specify the exact value since the real value of `DateTime` is not predictable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Roy Osherove suggests in [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.amazon.com/The-Art-Unit-Testing-examples/dp/1617290890) (page 134) to have a `SystemTime` class that provides a `.Now` and a way for tests to set what `.Now` returns. From there, it's just making sure everything uses that class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always going to struggle when you want to verify anything regarding `DateTime.Now` as the property value will most likely change between calls. The best you can do is something like this:

```
mockAnother.Verify(x => x.DoAnotherJob(It.Is<DateTime>(d > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1))), Times.Once);
```

The alternative is to introduce another class and abstraction which you use to resolve the `DateTime`:

```
public interface ITimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}

public class TimeProvider : ITimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now ; } }
}
```

Which you would then use instead of `DateTime.Now` directly:

```
public class MainJob
{
    private IAnother another;
    private ITimeProvider timeProvider;

    public MainJob(IAnother another, ITimeProvider timeProvider)
    {
        this.another = another;
        this.timeProvider = timeProvider;
    }

    public void FunctionA()
    {
        this.FunctionB(this.timeProvider.Now);
    }

    public void FunctionB(DateTime date)
    {
        this.another.DoAnotherJob(date);
    }
}
```

Then, your Unit Test becomes:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void FunctionATest()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var mockAnother = new Mock<IAnother>();
    var mockTimeProvider = new Mock<ITimeProvider>();
    mockTimeProvider.Setup(x => x.Now).Returns(now);

    var mainJob = new MainJob(mockAnother.Object, mockTimeProvider.Object);

    mainJob.FunctionA();

    mockAnother.Verify(x => x.DoAnotherJob(now), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I think I will take your first suggestion as my approach, since I always think it is too heavy to introduce something just to deal with `DateTime.Now`, I would bet on build server runs fast enough to execute the test cases within x seconds.